# VS Code extension command execution context

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing an extension and some commands can be executed directly from the Command Palette or right clicking into the file explorer.
The behavior I want should be slightly different depending from where the command has been triggered.
Is there a way to get the execution context without defining two different "entry points" ?

Comment: have you looked at the arguments you get from the different invocations

Comment: AFAIK there aren't any

Comment: I think you will indeed need two different commands.